# Calculate final letter grade in Python given 4 test scores

Tags: python, function

The question I have is asking me about final grades given 4 parameters (3 tests worth 20% and 1 final worth 40%) scored on a scale of 0 to 100 points. The function is supposed to be as simple as printing finalGrade(test1, test2, test3, final) which will output a letter grade depending on the score. I don't need to have the user input anything however I'm going to experiment once I have this basic code figured out.

This is my code so far:

```
def grader(testOne, testTwo, testThree, finalExam):
    first = testOne * .20
    second = testTwo * .20
    third = testThree * .20
    fourth = finalExam *.40
    finalGrade = first + second + third + fourth
    return finalGrade

def ?? (??):
    if grade >= 90 and <= 100:
        return("You received an A")

    elif grade >= 80 and < 90:
        return("You received a B")

    elif grade >= 70 and < 80:
        return("You received a C")

    elif grade >= 60 and < 70:
        return("You received a D")

    else grade < 60:
        return("Sorry, you received an F")

print(testOne, testTwo, testThree, finalExam) #will replace with values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
def ?? (??):
    if grade >= 90 and <= 100:
        return("You received an A")

    elif grade >= 80 and < 90:
        return("You received a B")

    elif grade >= 70 and < 80:
        return("You received a C")

    elif grade >= 60 and < 70:
        return("You received a D")

    else grade < 60:
        return("Sorry, you received an F")
```

Would be:

```
def gradeScores(FinalGrade):
    if FinalGrade >= 90 and FinalGrade <= 100:
        return("You received an A")

    elif FinalGrade >= 80 and FinalGrade < 90:
        return("You received a B")

    elif FinalGrade >= 70 and FinalGrade < 80:
        return("You received a C")

    elif FinalGrade >= 60 and FinalGrade < 70:
        return("You received a D")

    else:
        return("Sorry, you received an F")
```

And:

```
print(testOne, testTwo, testThree, finalExam) #will replace with values
```

Would be:

```
print(gradeScores(grader(testOne, testTwo, testThree, finalExam))) #will replace with values
```

Comment: `grade >= 90 and <= 100` isn't valid Python.  You'd need to mention `grade` twice or write `90 <= grade <= 100`.

Comment: i'm still receiving a syntax error for "else FinalGrade < 60:" ? is there supposed to be an else here?

Comment: Your welcome. Glad I could answer your question. Please select my answer as the right one.

Comment: @Regina click the check next to my answer if it fully answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments-

A.  Your second function, you use the variable "grade" ... that's a pretty good clue that "grade" should be the argument to the function.  You would try to name the function based on what it actually does... in this case, translate a number grade to a string.

B.  The "main" part of your script (where you call 'print') is lacking.  You don't need to actually access any of the internal parts of your functions from here- you pass values in and use the result.  Something like

```
grade1 = 90
...
finalgrade = grader(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4)
result = translategrade(finalgrade)
print(result)
```

is what you are looking for there.  You'll notice you don't access any of the private variables globally- you pass variables in, you use the return value on the way out.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but wanted to see how others were handling this and offer my own solution.

First, if you have a list of grades, first find the average.

```
# GREADES = [85, 92, 96, 67, 73]
def numerical_grade(grades):
    return (sum(grades) / float(len(grades))) / 100
```

Divide it by ten to get a float between 0 and 1. Then to get a letter grade, simply pull an index from the grade list by subtracting the grade from 10.

```
# GRADE = 0.75
def letter_grade(grade):
    grades = 'ABCDFFFFFF'
    if grade > 0:
        return grades[10 - ceil(grade * 10)]
    else
        return 'F'
```

Answer (score 0):

while True:

```
print("What is your Score out of 80?")
score = input()

first = int(input("What was your mark:"))
Marks = int(input("Enter what the test was out of :"))
result = first / Marks * 100
print(first ,"/" ,Marks, '*' ,100 ,"=" , result, "%" )





if result > 90:
    print("You received an A*")

elif result > 70 and 90 :
    print("You received a A")

elif result > 60 and 70 :
    print("You received a B")

elif result > 50 and 60 :
    print("You received a C")

elif result < 50:   
    print("You received an D, and have Failed")


ans = no
input("Would you like to continue using the program?")
```